# Scrapy - can't follow links due to encoding

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape some data from allabolag.se. I want to follow the links at e.g. http://www.allabolag.se/5565794400/befattningar but scrapy does not get the links correctly. It lacks "52" right after "%2" in the URL.

Example, I want to go to:
http://www.allabolag.se/befattningshavare/de_Sauvage-Nolting%252C_Henri_Jacob_Jan/f6da68933af6383498691f19de7ebd4b

But scrapy gets to following link:
http://www.allabolag.se/befattningshavare/de_Sauvage-Nolting%2C_Henri_Jacob_Jan/f6da68933af6383498691f19de7ebd4b

I read on this site that it got something to do with encodings: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Double_Encoding

How do I get around this?

My code is as follows:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import Request
from allabolag.items import AllabolagItem
from scrapy.loader.processors import Join


class allabolagspider(CrawlSpider):
    name="allabolagspider"
    # allowed_domains = ["byralistan.se"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.allabolag.se/5565794400/befattningar"
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow = "http://www.allabolag.se", restrict_xpaths=('//*[@id="printContent"]//a[1]')), callback='parse_link'),
    )

    def parse_link(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="printContent"]'):
            item = AllabolagItem()
            item['Byra'] = sel.xpath('/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/h1').extract()
            item['Namn'] = sel.xpath('/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/h1').extract()
            item['Gender'] = sel.xpath('/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/h1').extract()
            item['Alder'] = sel.xpath('/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/h1').extract()
            yield item
```

Comment: Are you getting any error while crawling ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the link extractor to not canonicalize the URLs by passing [`canonicalize=False`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html?#module-scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml)

Scrapy shell session:

```
$ scrapy shell http://www.allabolag.se/5565794400/befattningar
>>> from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
>>> le = LinkExtractor()
>>> for l in le.extract_links(response):
...     print l
...
(...stripped...)
Link(url='http://www.allabolag.se/befattningshavare/de_Sauvage-Nolting%2C_Henri_Jacob_Jan_Personprofil/f6da68933af6383498691f19de7ebd4b', text=u'', fragment='', nofollow=False)
(...stripped...)
>>> fetch('http://www.allabolag.se/befattningshavare/de_Sauvage-Nolting%2C_Henri_Jacob_Jan_Personprofil/f6da68933af6383498691f19de7ebd4b')
2016-03-02 11:48:07 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET http://www.allabolag.se/befattningshavare/de_Sauvage-Nolting%2C_Henri_Jacob_Jan_Personprofil/f6da68933af6383498691f19de7ebd4b> (referer: None)
>>> 

>>> le = LinkExtractor(canonicalize=False)
>>> for l in le.extract_links(response):
...     print l
... 
(...stripped...)
Link(url='http://www.allabolag.se/befattningshavare/de_Sauvage-Nolting%252C_Henri_Jacob_Jan_Personprofil/f6da68933af6383498691f19de7ebd4b', text=u'', fragment='', nofollow=False)
(...stripped...)
>>> 
>>> fetch('http://www.allabolag.se/befattningshavare/de_Sauvage-Nolting%252C_Henri_Jacob_Jan_Personprofil/f6da68933af6383498691f19de7ebd4b')
2016-03-02 11:47:42 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.allabolag.se/befattningshavare/de_Sauvage-Nolting%252C_Henri_Jacob_Jan_Personprofil/f6da68933af6383498691f19de7ebd4b> (referer: None)
```

So you should be good with:

```
class allabolagspider(CrawlSpider):
    name="allabolagspider"
    # allowed_domains = ["byralistan.se"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.allabolag.se/5565794400/befattningar"
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow = "http://www.allabolag.se",
                           restrict_xpaths=('//*[@id="printContent"]//a[1]'),
                           canonicalize=False),
             callback='parse_link'),
    )
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solved the problem!

Btw, please note that you forgot a comma after the following row: "restrict_xpaths=('//*[@id="printContent"]//a[1]')"